# Is it possible to pass a function with multiple fixed arguments to ::math::optimize::min_bound_1d in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm fairly new to Tcl and I'm stuck on an assignment/project I have to do.

So I have a function F(x, A1, A2,...) = y. x is a free variable and A1, A2 etc. are some constants that will be known in advance. I have to find x for when y is a minimum for multiple values of A1, A2 etc.

I came across the function ::math::optimize::min_bound_1d which looks exactly like what I need (there are some constraints on the function). The problem is that this optimize function only seems to accept functions with 1 argument.

So in my sudo code below I have something like:

```
proc F {x arg1 arg1} {
    # Crunch numbers
    return $result
}

foreach arg1 $list_of_first_args {
    foreach arg2 $list_of_second_args {
        # Is it possible to pass $arg1 and $arg2 to the function below?
        puts [::math_optimize_min_bound_1d F $lower_limit $upper_limit]
    }
}
```

Is it possible in Tcl to pass/bound $arg1 and $arg2 to the function F in the example above so that I can get x when y is a minimum for each permutation of argN? Can I put all the arguments in a list and pass that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provided you rearrange things a bit.

`F` needs to look like this, with the `x` variable placed last:

```
proc F {arg1 arg2 x} {
    # Crunch numbers
    return $result
}
```

(Or you can use a proxy command to rearrange argument order:)

```
proc F' {arg1 arg2 x} {
    tailcall F $x $arg1 $arg2
}
```

Then, inside the `foreach` structures:

```
puts [::math::optimize::min_bound_1d [list F $arg1 $arg2] $lower_limit $upper_limit]
```

The `[list F $arg1 $arg2]` thingy is a kind of a poor man's lambda that quite a few higher-order function commands in Tcl accept. If, at evaluation, `$arg1` is 1 and `$arg2` is 12, the "function" `{F 1 12}` is passed into `::math::optimize::min_bound_1d` and evaluated as `[concat {F 1 12} $x]`.

A "real" lambda could look like this:

```
[list x [concat F \$x $arg1 $arg2]]
```

but this construct can only be used if the higher-order function command is prepared to evaluate it using `apply $func $x`.

Documentation: [apply](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/apply.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [math::optimize](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/math/optimize.html) package, [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [tailcall](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tailcall.htm)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code in question doesn't try to do funky things like parsing the source of the function to optimise, the easiest way is to make a proxy function:

```
proc proxy {value} {
    global A1 A2
    F $value $A1 $A2
}
```

Then just optimize the proxy.

---

Though you're going to have to deal with the fact that optimizing in higher dimensions is much more complex than in the single-dimension case.